# How to avoid repetition of data in Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

In a web application I am binding the data to a `GridView`. In the `GridView` some of data is repeating. I want to not display the data again and again.

For example Empid is displaying more than one time in the same column. I want to not display the empid again in that column.

Comment: you should really do this filtering/grouping before sending your data to the gridview.Also a screenshot of that grid might be good with a part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the `OnDataBinding` event for the specific column you are using.  I never use `AutoGenerateColumns` so having fine control of each cell is pretty simple to implement.

Eg:

```
// Create global in your .cs file
string _currentEmpID = string.Empty;
```

Define your column like:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="ltEmpID" runat="server" 
                OnDataBinding="ltEmpID_DataBinding" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <!-- Your other columns... -->
</Columns>
```

Then just implement your `DataBinding` event:

```
protected void ltEmpID_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Literal lt = (Literal)(sender);
    string empID = Eval("EmpID").ToString();
    if (!empID.Equals(_currentEmpID))
    {
        lt.Text = empID;
        _currentEmpID = empID;
    }
    else
    {
        lt.Text = string.Empty;
    } 
}
```

The `RowDataBound` forces you to search for controls and if changes are required in the future you have the possibility of breaking other things being modified within the event.  Because of this, I prefer to use the control's `DataBinding` event whenever possible as it localizes functionality to only the control and gives you the flexability to swap out controls and functionality easily without the worry off affecting other things.

Answer (score 0):

If you group your data by the columns you don't want to repeat before binding it to your datasource you can bind an event to RowDataBound and check if the current value equals the previous and then hide the cell.

Check [this](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/06/gridview-very-simple-grouping.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the property AutoGenerateColumns in the gridview and assign it the value of false.

```
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```